# For each day I have volatility for country A and B. How to test if volatilities are different?

Tags: volatility

I have a dataset with 10Y benchmark government bond volatilities of two countries.
So, my data looks like this:

Date, Volatility5day_A, Volatility5day_B

The volatility measure itself is from Bloomberg with the following definition: "Measure of risk of price moves for a security calculated from the standard deviation of day to day logarithmic historical price changes." That is, the way I understand it, two countries can have different currencies.

I want to test if the volatility of country A is different from volatility of country B. What would be the best way to do that?

There might be a problem with overlapping. For example, today, say, on day t, the volatility is calculated from prices on days t-1, t-2, t-3, t-4, t-5. Tomorrow, on day t+1, the volatility will be calculated from prices on days t, t-1, t-2, t-3, t-4. Hence, there is a lot of overlap - does it make sense to have a dataset with daily data, or would it make more sense to have weekly data (e.g. for every Wednesday) - then there will be no overlap?

Finally, this volatility can be measured relative to close price, open price, high price or low price. Is any of these options better than the others or more common to use?

But again, the main question is - with this data, how can I test if volatility of country A is different from volatility of country B?

Thank you in advance! And have a great day!

Comment: It's more beneficial to use implied vol of ATM options with ~ 1 week expiry. Pick an options for the SPX equivalent of country A and B, then compare. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_volatility)

Comment: @THAT'SMYQUANTMYQUANTITATIV Thank you! I have heard about implied volatility before, but did not know that government bonds have some derivatives. So, which product would you take in order to calculate/get implied volatility from Bloomberg? I guess for each day I would need a price of a certain product (option?), and from that I should be able to compute implied volatility. But which product? As I said, I have 10Y bonds for both countries, so TTM is not exactly the same, but relatively close. Sorry if the question is too obvious.

Comment: I don't use Bloomberg, but generally you use any European option that encompasses the highest % of the market as possible. So if you wanted to know the volatility of the US stock market, you would calculate implied vol of SPX European calls and puts.

Comment: While it's no problem to trade government bond options OTC, it's not possible to get indicative quotes on Bloomberg because it's very uncommon to trade them. You could look at bond ETFs with options. It's also not Bey helpful to look at IV in this exercise in my opinion as you seem to care about actual volatility of the bonds? The most common is close to close and what Bloomberg does by default on HVT.